# Flutter & Firebase - Apple Sign In not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, apple-sign-in

I am trying to set up with apple sign in with the following code. When tapping the button nothing happens.

I get the following error:

```
Tried calling: authorizationCode
flutter: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'authorizationCode' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

How would I fix this?

```
Future<bool> get appleSignInAvailable => AppleSignIn.isAvailable();

  Future<User> appleSignIn() async {
    try {
      final AuthorizationResult appleResult =
          await AppleSignIn.performRequests([
        AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])
      ]);

      if (appleResult.error != null) {
        // handle errors from Apple
      }

      final AuthCredential credential =
          OAuthProvider('apple.com').credential(
        accessToken:
            String.fromCharCodes(appleResult.credential.authorizationCode),
        idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleResult.credential.identityToken),
      );

      UserCredential result =
          await Global.fbAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      User user = result.user;

      updateUserData(user);

      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iOS 14 simulator, this may be due to the [issue reported here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651533). The workaround would be to use a real device for debugging or use the iOS 13 simulator

Also, see this [thread](https://github.com/aboutyou/dart_packages/issues/144#issuecomment-703530824) for reference

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same kind of issue in one of my projects.You have to add your sha key in firebase and facebook to resolve the issue.

Also you can try the below code,

```
import 'package:apple_sign_in/apple_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AuthService {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<User> signInWithApple({List<Scope> scopes = const []}) async {
    // 1. perform the sign-in request
    final result = await AppleSignIn.performRequests(
        [AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: scopes)]);
    // 2. check the result
    switch (result.status) {
      case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        final appleIdCredential = result.credential;
        final oAuthProvider = OAuthProvider('apple.com');
        final credential = oAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.identityToken),
          accessToken:
              String.fromCharCodes(appleIdCredential.authorizationCode),
        );
        final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final firebaseUser = authResult.user;
        if (scopes.contains(Scope.fullName)) {
          final displayName =
              '${appleIdCredential.fullName.givenName} ${appleIdCredential.fullName.familyName}';
          await firebaseUser.updateProfile(displayName: displayName);
        }
        return firebaseUser;
      case AuthorizationStatus.error:
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_AUTHORIZATION_DENIED',
          message: result.error.toString(),
        );

      case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've already added the sha key to firebase

Comment: Can you show the errors if there are any.Put print statement to check.Also please verify that you have enabled Apple login in Authentication section of firebase

Comment: I've updated the question with the error message and yeah I've enabled Apple login in firebase

Comment: Can you try the code that i posted right now

Comment: Thanks for the code but unfortunately when using it I get errors in all my login files but I will try and see if I can adapt what you have sent with my existing code

Comment: It just doesn't work with my other code. I really need to find a solution based on my current code and the error I'm getting